# Using const void* instead of void*, for any type

Tags: c, pointers, constants, standards, c99

Pointer to void( `void*`)  is compatible with and can hold any other pointer type. Is that also true for a pointer to const void( `const void*` ).

Since:

*6.3.2.3, p2: For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
shall compare equal.*

Since I am allowed this:

```
int n = 0 ;
void* p = &n ;
```

I should have also been allowed this:

```
int n = 0 ;
const void* p = &n ;
```

This brings me to my final point, which is that all of this should also hold for compound literals.

```
void SomeFunc( const void* p ) { printf("%p",p) } ;

SomeFunc( &( int ){ 12345 } ) ;
```

Should be defined( and allowed ) by C Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll admit straight up I rarely find the need for compound literals in C, but your syntax is definitely well-founded. If I understand your question correctly, it is to attempt to determine whether the aforementioned address-of operator applied to a compound literal results in `const` vs non-const pointer.

It is non-const unless the compound itself is const-qualified. I don't have a C99 standard handy, but the best example I can foist for this is the instructive example in:

> **C11 standard §6.5.2.5 p11**
>
> A read-only compound literal can be specified through constructions like:
>
> ```
>   (const float []){1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6}
> ```

Coupled with the description of storage qualification of compound literals from:

> **C11 standard §6.5.2.5 p5**
>
> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

So the storage is there as well (i.e. its not residing in read-only memory somewhere). Unless `const` qualified, a compound literal is, in fact, non-const (the the data/elements therein if a compound literal array or structure may, in fact, have their own `const` qualification).

The mechanics of translation from `Type *` to either `void*` or `const void*` are hopefully obvious, but it is worth noting by some torquing of your sample:

```
void SomeFunc( void* p ) { printf("%p\n",p); } ;
void SomeFuncConst( const void* p ) { printf("%p\n",p); } ;

int main()
{
    SomeFunc( &( int ){ 12345 } ) ;        // OK. int* to void* 
    SomeFuncConst( &( int ){ 12345 } ) ;   // OK. int* to const void*
    SomeFuncConst &(const int){12345} );  // OK. const int* to const void*
    SomeFunc( &( const int ){ 12345 } ) ;  // ERROR. const int* not allowed as void*
}
```

Given all of that , it is entirely plausible I misunderstood your question, and if so kindly clarify as i reach for the delete-link.

Comment: Yeah I missed that you have two functions.

Comment: Yeah my problem was conversion from type* and const type* to const void*.

Comment: I guess I have to trust you on the const int* to const void*.

Comment: @2501 its directly to translatable to `const void*` which can literally (pun intended) hold any *data* pointer you can conceive. If that is truly the crux of your question (`const int*` somehow becomes `const void*`) it has *nothing* to do with compound literals. If it is a question of what *type* of pointer is cleaved from a compound literal, that I (likely feebly) explore above.

Comment: I guess the compound literal was a unintentional red herring.

Comment: I tried looking for similar answers but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with this call

```
SomeFunc( &( int ){ 12345 } ) ;
```

A similar example there is in the C Standard

```
drawline(&(struct point){.x=1, .y=1},
         &(struct point){.x=3, .y=4});
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
>   if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
>   the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.

It seems there is a gap in the C Standard relative to conversions. A more detailed implicit conversions are described in the C++ Standard

1 Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:

— Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion.

— Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and boolean conversions.

— Zero or one qualification conversion.

Thus as it is seen the standard conversion sequence includes one pointer conversion and and one qualification conversions.

The C Standard could give a similar detailed description.

Comment: What is the prototype of drawline. Does it take const void*?

Comment: @2501 As it follows from the example the functopn accepts two pointers to struct point. Nievertheless any pointer can be implicitly converted to void pointer. So there is no problem with const void *.

Comment: Your last statement does not follow logically from the former one. Could you elaborate in the answer?

Comment: @2501 Conversion from a pointer to a void pointer and conversion from a void pointer to a const void pointer are implicit conversions. I think that the Standard should be edited in this part that it would be more clear that these two implicit conversions can be applied to one expresion.